# Invalid syntax for print function in for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

Today I have been learning a "for loop" in Python. I type the code in Python Shell and `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` appears after the function `print("I finished")` with the word `print` in red.

```
words = ["cat", "125", "dog", "pig"]
for word in words:
    if word == "125":
        print("No spam please!")
        break
    print("Nice " + word)
else:
    print("I am lucky: No spam.")
print("I finished")
```

But when I write the code in Notepad and save as `*.py` and than run with Command Prompt it works correctly and comes:

```
Nice cat
No spam please!
I finished
```

What is with the third "print" function wrong?

Comment: I do not understand why does "invalid syntax" appear. In command prompt it works correctly.

Comment: you probably had some cr+lf mixed with some cr only end of lines.
Notepad must have corrected this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In interactive Python shells, you usually need to leave an empty line between the end of an outermost if/else/for/while/whatever block and the beginning of the next statement.

```
else: 
    print("I am lucky: No spam.") 

print("I finished")
```

---

As a simpler example: No empty line causes an error:

```
>>> if True:
...     print("!")
... print("finished")
  File "<stdin>", line 3
    print("finished")
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Leaving an empty space causes it to work:

```
>>> if True:
...     print("!")
...
!
>>> print("finished")
finished
```

Generally speaking, try not to start new statements on "continuation lines" that begin with "...". Press Enter until you see ">>>", and then you're good to go.

Comment: It really would have been better to show this in Python 3 instead of 2, because a novice using 3.x is likely to be confused your also-a-SyntaxError-in-3.x `print` statements.

Comment: I like the last sentence you added at the end, too. (The only problem is when you're trying to paste into the terminal, and you can't always avoid it… but if you're doing a lot of pasting into the terminal, you probably want IPython or an IDE anyway…)